# Play old Lego.com games Junkbot and Worldbuilder, saving progress

Tags: technical-issues, pc

Back in the day, Lego.com had some excellent games. I particularly enjoyed:

- Junkbot
- Junkbot Undercover (a.k.a. Junkbot 2)
- Worldbuilder
- Worldbuilder 2

These games are no longer on Lego.com, but are mirrored on some other sites. I'm wondering if there are currently any ways to play them, online or offline, with the ability to save progress?

(Feel free to suggest tags for this; I couldn't find many applicable ones.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://biomediaproject.com/bmp/lmp/games/ Go to that site, and then download 'Game Archive 3.0.0 Part 3' It might take a bit to download, since it has those games you mentioned and more (like Backlot) but you should be able to play it offline then. You will have to download XAMPP for it to work, though. The instructions on installing should be in there for each game. They ALL save progress, I believe (although I've only checked for WorldBuilder) and JunkBot 1 + Undercover have both save-versions and versions where all the levels are already unlocked.

If you need anymore help, I MIGHT be able to provide it, although I've only recently discovered this myself.

Comment: This worked for all four games! Thank you so much! I have been wanting to play these games for a long time.

Answer (score 4):

Lego Junkbot, Junkbot Undercover, Worldbuilder, and Worldbuilder 2 are playable through [Flashpoint Archive](https://flashpointarchive.org/). Simply install Flashpoint Infinity and search for the game you want to play.

Note: Worldbuilder threw an error about a director file the first time I tried playing, but it went away after I relaunched the game a few times.

[image: Playing Lego Worldbuilder on Flashpoint]

[image: Playing Lego Junkbot on Flashpoint]