# Playing an old shockwave game integrated with an archived website

Tags: flash, life-expectancy-service-x-day

I'm trying to figure out if there's any way to play the online version of the old Namco arcade machine *Life Expectancy Service X-Day* from 1993. The arcade version was never emulated, but the Namco wiki links a web based version that is archived via the Wayback Machine:

http://web.archive.org/web/20010216073756/http://www.nifty.ne.jp:80/XDAY/play.html

However, this version seems to be based on web navigation controlled by a Shockwave plugin. Since Flash and Shockwave are now dead, it obviously cannot be used properly in any current browsers, and it doesn't seem to have any versions in the current build of BlueMaxima Flashpoint. I've tried some alternative methods - the DCR file embedded in the Wayback page can be downloaded and run in an external Shockwave projector, but because of how it seems to be integrated with functions on the webpage itself, the file alone isn't much use. I've also attempted to load the page in K-Meleon browser, but it always result in either a failure to load or a crash.

Any idea on how this version of the game could be accessed?

Comment: Maybe check https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/379192/how-can-i-keep-playing-online-only-flash-games-after-the-flash-shutdown-in-2020 and see if it applies.

Comment: It's unfortunately not archived on [Flashpoint](https://flashpointarchive.org/).